# Android unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, wait

While testing Android app with Android test framework, how do I make the test wait for I am waiting for a network response before I proceed. I do not want to use Thread.sleep as it is not certain how long do I want to wait. Also tried waitForIdleSync() but it does not seem to work. Is there any other way?

I have the enterCredentials method which enters username and password and clicks the log in button. I need to wait for sometime before it gets a user object and saves it in database before I get the user object to validate the credentials. I want an alternative to Thread.sleep() here. I have already tried waitForIdleSync() but that does not seem to work.

```
@Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mActivity = getActivity();
        enterCredentials();      
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        testLoggedInUser();

    }

    public void testLoggedInUser() {
        mMyApplication = this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
        User user = mMyApplication.getUser();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        assertEquals(EMAIL, email);
    }

    public void enterCredentials() {

        final EditText mUsername = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.email);
        final EditText mPassword = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.password);
        final Button login = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.logIn);
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                mUsername.setText(EMAIL);
                mPassword.setText(PASSWORD);
                login.performClick();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: ..what?? Please refine your question, since I cannot understand what your question is..

Comment: what kind of test are you running?, except for acceptances/integration tests your test should be fast and independent, you should mock/spy/... your boundaries, specially network request

Comment: I am trying to test a login feature in my app where in I enter credentials and send a post request and the server returns me with a user object. So while testing I want to wait for to receive this user object and then I can validate the user credentials. So how do I make the test wait in this case.

Comment: Please also show some code that you have tried.

Comment: Can someone please take off the hold now.

Answer (score 1):

You can run two threads inside one big thread. One thread will wait for the connection sync. You can make that into an if statement or whatever and have time control that will call the other thread only if synchronization succeeds. If the time limit is reached for which you don't want the test to run you can exit the application or whatever you want to do. As such you will actually avoid using the Thread.sleep() and will also have some time control.

But Thread.sleep() with small intervals and an if statement to check if the connection finally succeeded seems to be the way to go if you don't want to wait too long. Just get some tries before you exit.